# Math behind Xavier initialization?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning

In [Glorot 2010](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v9/glorot10a/glorot10a.pdf) Section 4.2.1, the author states that in formula (6)

$$
Var\left[\dfrac{\partial Cost}{\partial s^i}\right]
=
Var\left[\dfrac{\partial Cost}{\partial s^d}\right]
\prod_{i'=i}^{d}n_{i' +1}Var\left[W^{i'}\right] 
$$
where $s^i$ is the activation output from layer $i$ and $n_{i}$ is the number of neurons in layer $i$, where $s^i = z^i W^i + b^i$ are the linear transformation between layers.

Can anyone derive formula (6) from formula (2):
$$
\dfrac{\partial Cost}{\partial s^i_k} 
= 
f'(s_k^i) W^{i+1}_{k,\dots}  \dfrac{\partial Cost}{\partial s^{i+1}}
$$

The problem here is that $W^{i+1}_{k,\dots}$ and $\dfrac{\partial Cost}{\partial s^{i+1}}$ are not independent to each other ($\dfrac{\partial Cost}{\partial s^{i+1}}$ is a function of the output layer.)